# Why its not showing anything when i open the app with url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, url-scheme

I have following setup, when i open my app (app number 2 open by app number 1 using url)  using url in iPhone 7, then i am not getting any url inputs.

its not showing any alert box at all. 
How do i check if i am receiving the url input in my app at all or not?

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    //if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
    //[self.ViewController handleOpenURL:url];
    //}
  id test = (NSURL *) url;
  UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                                message:test
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
  //NSLog(@">>> got <<< >>> <<< !!!! >>>> : %@", url);
  return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application 
    openURL:(NSURL *)url 
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

... is a UIApplicationDelegate method. So it can't be located in *ViewController.m*. It needs to be in *AppDelegate.m*.

Comment: I put that now in AppDelegate.m  but one error i am getting `/Users/sun/Desktop/iphone/AppDelegate.m:16:9: No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'`

Comment: Sure, you'll have totally different errors. But that's not what you asked. The problem was "then i am not getting any url inputs". Well, now you are! So that problem is solved. Done. Take out the `present` stuff and put the `NSLog` back in, and you will see.